# Mercurial Log of Merges Between Named Branches

Tags: mercurial

I've got a PowerShell script that finds revisions that merged two named branches together.  It loops  through all the merges on a particular branch, showing changesets that have a parent on the other named branch.

Is there an `hg log` command that will do the equivalent?  I've played around with Mercurial's revsets feature (`hg help revsets`), but can't seem to find the magical incantation.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use this:

```
hg log --rev "merge() and branch(default) and children(branch(secondary))"
```

This will output all changesets that are:

1. Merge-changesets
2. *on* the default-branch
3. A direct child of any changeset on the secondary branch